# How do you enable JMX remoting or custom Java args with Railo?

Tags: tomcat, jmx, railo

Where do you go to edit the Java args in Railo to set up JMX remoting so that I can monitor the JVM with jVisualVM or other java monitoring tools?

In the Apache Tomcat Railo Properties, under the Java tab I have attempted adding the following arguments:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8701
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

When I boot up the Railo service I get an error in my `Railo-stderr.log` which states:

```
2013-06-07 17:55:07 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Error: Invalid com.sun.management.jmxremote.port number: 8702 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I can successfully use the exact same set of arguments with my CF9, except I'm using port 8701 for CF. Do I possibly need to boot up my Railo in a different manner?

As far as environment. I am using Railo 4.0.4.001, with Tomcat and the IIS BonCode adapter. I also have a copy of CF9 running on my machine.

Comment: I may be off the right track (and don't have my PC to hand) but I set up remote JMX or debugging recently on Railo/Tomcat and you're editing in the right place, but the java arguments text area is very picky about newlines being present or not in what you enter. however it's set up in your server isn't correct, as the JVM is telling you that everything from the port number onwards/downwards is being passed in as one line.

Comment: Do you know if newlines need to be preset or not present? I'm guessing not present? If so I'll give it a swing tomorrow to see what it results in.

Comment: I'm back on the right machine now. It uses newlines between each entry, no spaces trailing or leading on each line. The values can also be got to in the registry at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Java\Options (on a 64 bit Windows) or HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Java\Options (on 32-bit)

Comment: Yup, that's it. Each argument on it's own line and no trailing whitespace. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Glad it's working. I've added the comment in as a proper answer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomcat uses the [Apache Commons ProcRun Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) to run as a Windows service.

When editing the Java options through the GUI (typically by running [tomcat]\bin\Tomcat7w.exe) each command line option needs to be on it's own line without leading or trailing spaces. Because of the size of the text area you're given to edit the Java options, its easy to paste in several options and not notice that each option isn't separated by newlines. I've done this a few times.

In your case, the clue is that the Java error shows a property which chould be a port and is actually a port, plus other options. The kind of error behavior you get though will completely depend on the validation present on the first option on a given line.

[image: ScreenShot of Java Options Dialog]

As well as editing the options in the dialog, you can also get to them in the registry at the following locations:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Java\Options` (on a 64 bit Windows) or

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\Tomcat7\Parameters\Java\Options` (on 32-bit)